Garuda visiting Sri Ram in Ramayan
In Ramayan, when Garuda visited Sri Ram and Laxman to save from Naag fans, Sri Ram behaved as if he doesn't know Garuda. Well Sri Ram has had his education in Gurukul and must be knowing about Garuda.
From Hanuman Challisa, when Hanumanji get Mountain for Laxman, Sri Ram Ji said " Sahasra badan tum hare jash gawe, asakahi Sri Pati kantha Lagawe"
It clearly shows Sri Ram knew about Shesh Naag from the human aspects. It can be assumed that he should be knowing about Vishnu and his Vahana, Garuda. So why did he behave with Garuda like he didn't know?
